# Use item name stored in old for loop, inside a new for loop

Tags: python, json, for-loop, beautifulsoup, request

This program I'm working on is going to search through multiple paths (located in a JSON list) of a URL and find one that's not being used (404 page).

The problem = I want to print what the path is when I come across a 404 (when I can find an error div). But I can't figure out a way to do so, since the item name seems unreachable.

```
### Libraries ###
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import grequests
import requests
import json
import time

### User inputs ###
namelist = input('Your namelist: ')
print('---------------------------------------')
result = input('Output file: ')
print('---------------------------------------')

### Scrape ###
names = json.loads(open(namelist + '.json').read())
reqs = (grequests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/id/' + name) for name in names)
resp=grequests.imap(reqs, grequests.Pool(10))

for r in resp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    findelement = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"error_ctn"})

    if (findelement):
        print(name)

    else:
        print('trying')
```

Comment: Why do you need to search for a div when each response contains a `status_code`? Why not just check that for `404`?  On the same note, each response contains a `url` attribute that is the `name` you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by modifying where your for loop is located. I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using so I've left a comment where you might need to modify the code further, but something along these lines should work:

```
names = json.loads(open(namelist + '.json').read())

for name in names:

    req = grequests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/id/' + name)

    # May need to modify this line since only passing one req, so are assured of only one response
    resp=grequests.imap(req, grequests.Pool(10))

    # There should only be one response now.

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    findelement = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"error_ctn"})

    if (findelement):
        print(name)

    else:
        print('trying')
```